# Test for all possibilities in a string

Tags: c#, string, linq, c#-4.0

I am trying to test (compare against another value in memory) for all possible combinations in a string but wanted to know what the best way is to do it.

My input string is `0246`, the trick is that each number can be one of 2 options, for instance:

```
[0,1][2,3][4,5][6,7]
```

I want to be able to flip through all possible combinations, it's kind of like cracking a safe but that is not the purpose of this, I promise!

I was thinking of doing a `foreach` loop to switch through each option but my loops would be nested and I know performance will take a hit, since Linq is like the new black, can this be done using that?

UPDATE*

I want the result to return in order from low to high as my original string that I am comparing against could be 0001 but doesn't make sense to randomly jump around.

I also want to keep track of how many times I had to generate a different variation of this and note that down as it will be used at a later time.

Comment: I'm not a c# programmer, but this looks like an ideal candidate for a regex: /^[01][23][45][67]$/

Comment: "I know performance will take a hit" - so you expect LINQ version to produce the same number of combination as nested `for`/`foreach`, but with better performance ????

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov poor wording, but I think he meant using LINQ would reduce performance (which, most likely, it would).

Comment: Since each button could be one of two numbers are you trying to find out the Number combinations or the Button combinations?

Comment: You say "test possibilities", but then say you want to generate all combinations.  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry about my poor wording, I sometimes type like I'm talking and I sometimes skip important details :p

So I want to generate a variation of the string and then compare (test) it against another value. If it matches, great! If not then keep going till you hit. I hope that clears things up a bit...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that works for any number of inputs (after parsing your format into `int[][]`), using [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) and [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join.aspx):

```
var data = new[]
{
    new[] { 0, 1 },
    new[] { 2, 3 },
    new[] { 4, 5 },
    new[] { 6, 7 },
};
var nums = data.Aggregate(new[] { "" }.AsEnumerable(),
        (agg, arr) => agg.Join(arr, x => 1, x => 1, (i, j) => i.ToString() + j));
```

Outputs:

```
0246 
0247 
0256 
0257 
0346 
0347 
0356 
0357 
1246 
1247 
1256 
1257 
1346 
1347 
1356 
1357
```

It uses LINQ, so it's probably not the fastest thing ever (still < 1 ms for me with this data), and something smells about how I'm using `Join` with fixed join values, so it's probably not the best thing ever, but hey - it works.

I'm assuming you actually need all the values listed out. If all you're really trying to do is see if the value matches something that looks like a valid passcode, a regex like [Dmitry's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059517/781792) is probably the way to go.

Comment: I like this approach as it goes in order from low to high as my target value that I will be comparing against (testing) can be anyone of these so jumping around generating different variations doesn't make sense. I will be able to test this hopefully tonight and will report back

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean this:

```
var allCombinations = from a in new[] { "0", "1", }
                      from b in new[] { "2", "3", }
                      from c in new[] { "4", "5", }
                      from d in new[] { "6", "7", }
                      select a + b + c + d;
```

Or more fancily:

```
var allCombinations = from a in "01"
                      from b in "23"
                      from c in "45"
                      from d in "67"
                      select string.Concat(a, b, c, d);
```

In the latter (fancy) version `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are `char` variables, and `string.Concat(a, b, c, d)` could also be written `a.ToString() + b + c + d`.

Comment: This is good if you always have 4 positions/digits. Otherwise, a more general solution like mine is better.

Answer (score 1):

To test the value you have im memory you don't need to generate all possible values. Generating full string and compairing it is the worse way to do this job.

If you want to control the process of compairing (count operations) you can't use any built-in methods(regular expressions or `Linq`). You should manually go through all the chars in string and check them.

```
public bool Test(string input, string[] possibleValues)
{
    int operationsCount = 0;
    if (input.Length != possibleValues.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        bool found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < possibleValues[i].Length; j++)
        {
            operationsCount++;
            if (input[i] == possibleValues[i][j])
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value does not satisfies the condition. Number of operations: " + operationsCount);
            return false;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Value satisfies the condition. Number of operations: " + operationsCount);
    return true;
}

Test("0247", new string[] { "01", "23", "45", "67" });
```

The shortest way is to can use [Regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to check if the input string satisfies the condition. Regular expressions are build for matching strings to specific pattert. The only problem in this solution: you can not determine how many operations you made.

```
public bool Test(string input, string[] possibleValues)
{
    String pattern = GeneratePattern(possibleValues);
    bool result = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
    if (!result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value does not satisfies the condition.");
        }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value satisfies the condition.");
    }
    return result;
}

private string GeneratePattern(string[] possibleValues)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("^");
    foreach (var possibleValue in possibleValues)
    {
        sb.Append("[");
        sb.Append(possibleValue);
        sb.Append("]");
    }
    sb.Append("$");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: (redacted) I suppose it can do either way. OP says "test for" but then mentions LINQ and possibilities.

Comment: Question confuses me too, but i think the purpose is to check the input string.

Comment: So one of the goals is to determine the amount of times I cycle through teh combinations and to note that value down, does this approach provide that? I will update my question with this additional information. Also, by "test" I mean comparing against another value I am holding in memory.

Comment: I'm dumb. I can use foreach loop on this to determine the count. I will test this out hopefully tonight and report back, thank you.